# create a file using Cat in terminal and pass the file to another command

Tags: pipe, zsh, cat

I have CLI command which works great when the file is created somewhere outside and the filename input is given to the command.

For eg:

```
mycli create rr --filename ./example/rule.yaml (works perfectly)
```

But let's say when someone has not created a file and want to create a file in terminal, give it a name and pass the file name to the command, how the command will look like?

I tried like below:

```
cat <<EOF | mycli create rr --filename -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  password: password
  username: username
EOF
```

Above way gives an error saying no such file or directory

Comment: As @Taschi replied, you need create a temporary file, otherwise, your "mycli" regarding the whole multiple line strings as the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
export FILENAME=`mktemp`
cat <<EOF > $FILENAME
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  password: password
  username: username
EOF
mycli create rr --filename $FILENAME
rm $FILENAME
export FILENAME=""
```

(untested, not at my Linux machine right now, but should work I guess)

Comment: This solution should work. I think you can use `unset FILENAME` instead of `export FILENAME=""`